# Windows and Ubuntu Dual Boot both broken due to update

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 22.10

I'm facing a huge problem: Ubuntu had some updates to do. After installing the updates I couldn't boot Ubuntu due to this error :

```
"Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Invalid Parameter    
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Invalid Parameter    
start_image() return Invalid parameter, falling back to default loader
```

Then I found a solution online saying that I should run this command below under windows :

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

After executing and restarting the computer I keep getting this error when booting to windows now:

```
 "Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\??S - Invalid Parameter    
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\??S - Invalid Parameter    
start_image() return Invalid parameter, falling back to default loader
```

So both of my OS are now broken and I don't have a bootable device anymore. What can I do to fix this? I tried repairing with OS Support Recovery but still did not work...

Does anyone have a fix for this issue please.

Comment: Windows bootloaders are entirely separate from grub.  Just use the EFI menu (some key at power-up) and select Windows, avoiding grub compeletly.

Comment: That's what I did even when selecting Windows I get the grub